# Adding friends on Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Just downloaded Pokemon Go app for Iphone. Can you be friends with other users or is it just an independent game?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately there's no friendlist available yet. However you can join the same team as your friends when you reach level 5, and together you can claim gyms and have fun.

Answer (score 0):

There is no friends list yet but was said to soon be an option. As for now when you reach level 5 and above you can have a team, later in the game there are battles as well. Enjoy playing fellow collector <3